# Ruby on rails Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have User model, it has some validations and they work on create. But when i call any user from database as `@user=User.find(1) @user.valid?` it returns false. Could you help me?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, :surname, :username,  :phone, :role, :gender, :presence => true

  validates :password_confirmation, :email_confirmation, :presence => true

  validates :username, :email, :uniqueness => true

  validates :verified, :bulletin, :inclusion => { :in => [true, false] }

  validates :password,:email, :confirmation => true

  ....

end
```

Comment: you can do user.errors to get the validations that fail

Comment: i think the issue is that after getting object from database doesnt have password and passsword_confirmation and email_confirmation

Comment: You think, or you know? Have you checked @user.errors ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to add `on: :create` param for each validations that only need to be run on create. 
For example when you're doing `@user.valid?` I gess you don't want to check if password_confirmation is present.
So in this case it should be: 
`validates :password_confirmation, :email_confirmation, :presence => true, :on => :create`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: But i need to check if user tries to update password or email otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special validation for this use case, that the user should provide a confirmation, but the confirmation is not stored in the database

```
validates :email, confirmation: true, :uniqueness => true
validates :password, confirmation: true, ....
```

This substitutes the validation for `:password_confirmation` and `:email_confirmation`, so you need also to remove them.

See the fine rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#confirmation